# Extracting characters except digits in Pandas column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Trying to remove all characters except digits in dataframe column, that has object type and mixed value for age, for example: `'44', '60', 'July 89', 'August 42'`

Here is the approach which I'm using with `extract()`:

```
data['age'] = data.age.str.extract('(\d+)')
```

For some reason the output of the column is NaN values. I tried different approaches (for example, with `replace()` function) but still is the same issue. Can you give me some hint for fixing that? Thanks!

Comment: Try `data['age'] = data['age'].astype(str).str.extract(r'(\d+)', expand=False)`

Comment: works without expand=False, I think the main thing is astype(str) in this case. Many thanks for the answer, gentleman :)

Comment: Needs to be a string for a `.str` method to work... hence why `astype(str)` makes it work

Comment: All you had to do was add a `r` before `'(\d+)'`

Comment: @JoeFerndz that is incorrect. It is unrelated to the regex string. The df itself is of type object, not of type string

Comment: see `data=pd.DataFrame({"age":[44, '60', 'July 89', 'August 42']})` vs `data=pd.DataFrame({"age":['44', '60', 'July 89', 'August 42']})`. Having `44` as str vs int makes all the difference

Comment: I think data was presented as strings so my response was based on that info. If the data does contain integers, then yes we have to convert the dtype to astype(str) before we apply str to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expression methods only work on strings. It appears your data is of mixed type, including numbers and strings.

It  makes sense to first cast all data to string type, then you can proceed to extract the numbers:

```py
data['age'] = data['age'].astype(str).str.extract(r'(\d+)')
```